# JAVA jps command shows nothing

Tags: java

I just installed HADOOP 2.8.0 and I tried to check the list of java processes using jps command but it shows nothing.

I already checked environment variables for JAVA_HOME and it works fine as I tried javac -version and java -version.

Is it supposed to show at least one jps? It seems like the command works but shows nothing.

[image]

Comment: Did you try $ sudo jps?

Comment: @Vebbie does it work on windows too?

Comment: No. The sudo command is Not for windows. In windows we generally do ‘run as administrator’. If you’re working with windows then try to restart Hadoop you’ve installed and then hit ‘jps’ again

Comment: @Vebbie thanks alot but it has nothing to do with hadoop error right? Even without hadoop the command should work right?

Comment: Yes. It should. But installing new services especially in windows sometimes require reboot of machine or service itself in order to function properly.

Answer (score 0):

The JPS command is limited to reporting information on JVMs for which it has the access permissions.
Mostly, because of permission issues, you might not be able to see the list of hotspot VMs.

I faced a similar one in Hadoop EMR (Linux based), with sudo user I was able to list the items.

Without sudo user:

```
[anishg@ip-10-22-18-22 ~]$ jps
31884 Jps
```

As a sudo user

```
[root@ip-10-22-18-22 anishg]# jps
23680 RESTServer
4902 Jps
23305 ThriftServer
15436 Main
22862 QuorumPeerMain
21071 ResourceManager
8464 Main
19795 WebAppProxyServer
18803 JobHistoryServer
17109 NameNode
22229 Bootstrap
8537 Main
22458 Bootstrap
23930 HMaster
18524 ApplicationHistoryServer
28255 Main
```

Hope it could be a reason for empty jps

Comment: More on jps - https://docs.oracle.com/en/java/javase/17/docs/specs/man/jps.html